# LeadBolt from Unity crash

Tags: android, sdk, leadbolt

I registered on leadblot. Download their SDK.
Create folder in my project: Plugins->Android.
Copy AndroidManifest in this folder and sdk which i download.
That's all I did in the example that was in the folder with the SDK.
This file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1plndrafMw-jBQT6RfUL8H9TfbJcHlh_LgtxPXnLLXIU/pub
My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.ALTIMGAMES.SUV" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" /> 
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.hewzyntzcrsflwjnemv.ReEngagement" />
    <service android:name="com.hewzyntzcrsflwjnemv.ReEngagementService" />
    <service android:name="com.hewzyntzcrsflwjnemv.AdBootReceiverService" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

My c# code(where i use adbolt):
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LeadBoltAD : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
    AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    using(AndroidJavaObject ad = new AndroidJavaObject("com.unity.wrapper.LeadBoltUnity", jo)){
     ad.Call("loadAd","820080475");
   }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}
I install my app. When app start he is crash..
Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 
`<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />`

to

`<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />`

as explained in Step 6 of the readme file that you posted.

Besides that, I'd need more information to be able to help. From the command-line you can launch adb logcat with your test phone plugged into your computer to stream any error messages back to your console. That can be useful for finding specific errors.